# How to output all accept items for repair, the deadline for issuance of which is 2 days

Tags: sql

Can you help me to solve this:

To bring out all accepted items for repair, the deadline for issuance of which is 2 days

That's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Date_of_acceptance DATE,
    Date_of_deadline DATE,
    Status_order NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Type_of_repair NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Price DECIMAL (20),
    EmployeeID INT,
    CustomerID INT,
    ItemsID INT
);

CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Items  
( 
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemsName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Status_items NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CompServises 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ServisesName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PriceOfServise DECIMAL(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO CompServises (ServisesName, PriceOfServise)
VALUES ('Change of battery', 55);
INSERT INTO CompServises (ServisesName, PriceOfServise)
VALUES('Upgrade motherboard', 550);
INSERT INTO CompServises (ServisesName, PriceOfServise)
VALUES('Repair printers', 45);


ALTER TABLE Orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Employee 
        FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(ID)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customer 
        FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(ID)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Items 
        FOREIGN KEY (ItemsID) REFERENCES Items(ID)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES('Yavor', 'Dimitrov');
INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES('Aleko', 'Ivanov');
INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES('Boris', 'Petrov');
INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES('Alex', 'Georgiev');


INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ('Nikolai', 'Georgiev','0889-125-521' );
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ('Viktoriya', 'Dimitrova', '0899-187-784' );
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ('Aneliya', 'Petkova', '0885-748-748' );
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ( 'Petyr', 'Stoyanov', '0887-878-777');
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ('Elena', 'Dimitrova', '0895-741-547' );
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ( 'Dimityr', 'Angelov', '0897-546-345');
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ('Alexandra', 'Dimova', '0885-321-764');
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ('Viktor', 'Hristov' , '0874-436-987');
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ( 'Petya', 'Dimitrova', '0889-765-743');
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber)
VALUES ( 'Atanas', 'Petkov', '0888-463-675');

INSERT INTO Items (ItemsName, Status_items)
VALUES ( 'Printer', 'Accept for the repair ');
INSERT INTO Items (ItemsName, Status_items)
VALUES ( 'Computer', 'Unclaimed');
INSERT INTO Items (ItemsName, Status_items)
VALUES ('Laptop', 'Accept for the repair');
INSERT INTO Items (ItemsName, Status_items)
VALUES ( 'Monitor', 'Unclaimed');
INSERT INTO Items (ItemsName, Status_items)
VALUES ('Battery' , 'Unclaimed' );
INSERT INTO Items (ItemsName, Status_items)
VALUES ('Computer' , 'Accept for repair' );

INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES('2021-11-16', '2021-11-18','Accept','Broken screen of laptop', 100, 1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES ('2021-10-9', '2021-10-15','Submitted','Broken printer',90,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES ('2021-9-3', '2021-9-23','Waiting for delivery of part','Rеplacing the motherboard',500,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES ('2021-8-2', '2021-8-26','Accept','Repair a broken computer',600, 2,2,2);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES('2021-7-12', '2021-7-14','Accept','Change the laptop battery', 120,2,2,2);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES ('2021-6-10', '2021-6-18','Submitted','Update windows',30,2,2,2);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES ('2021-2-6', '2021-2-21','Waiting for delivery of part',' Rеplacing the motherboard ',500,3,3,3);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES ('2021-4-3', '2021-4-25','Waiting for delivery of part',' Virus scan',25,3,3,3);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES ('2021-5-16', '2021-5-30','Accept',' Change the laptop battery',120,3,3,3);
INSERT INTO Orders( Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_order, Type_of_repair, Price, EmployeeID, CustomerID, ItemsID)
VALUES ('2021-3-5', '2021-3-5','Submitted','Update windows',30,4,4,4);
```

I did this, but I don't know if it's right:

```
SELECT 
    ItemsName, Status_items, Date_of_acceptance, Date_of_deadline, Status_items
FROM 
    Orders
INNER JOIN 
    Items ON Orders.ID = Items.ID
WHERE 
    Date_of_deadline = '2021-11-18'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess

> ```
> SELECT 
>   itm.ItemsName
> , ord.Price
> --, Status_items
> --, Date_of_acceptance
> --, Date_of_deadline
> --, Status_order
> FROM Orders AS ord
> JOIN Items AS itm ON ord.ID = itm.ID
> WHERE ord.Status_order = 'Accept'
>   AND itm.Status_items = 'Accept for the repair' 
>   AND ord.Date_of_deadline <= DATEADD(day, 2, ord.Date_of_acceptance)
> ```

> ```
> ItemsName | Price
> :-------- | ----:
> Printer   |   100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b956a4f09321e66c0761c7a3a6a4bbe3)*